# Kafka not deleting key with tombstone

Tags: apache-kafka

I create a kafka topic with below properties

**min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01,delete.retention.ms=100,segment.ms=100,cleanup.policy=compact**

Let's say I insert k-v pairs in order **1111:1, 1111:2, 1111:null, 2222:1**
What happens now is except last message, the log compaction runs on rest of the messages and clears first two but retains **1111:null**

Acc to the documentation,

```
Kafka log compaction also allows for deletes. A message with a key and a null payload acts like a tombstone, a delete marker for that key. Tombstones get cleared after a period.
```

So, I am hoping when delete.retention.ms is achieved, the null marker should delete the message with key **1111**

I have two questions - Why is the tombstone marker not working? Why is the last message ignored from compaction?

This is what server.properties file has -

```
log.retention.ms=100
log.retention.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=100
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=100
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.01
```

Answer (score 25):

Tombstone records are preserved longer by design. The reason is, that brokers don't track consumers. Assume, that a consumer goes offline for some time after reading the first record. While the consumer is down, log compaction kicks. If log compaction would delete the tombstone record, the consumer would never learn about the fact, that the record was deleted. If the consumer implements a cache, it could happen that the record gets never deleted. Thus, tombstone are preserved longer to allow offline consumer to receive all tombstones for local cleanup.

Tombstone will be deleted only after `delete.retention.ms` (default value is 1 day). Note: this is a topic level configuration and there is no broker level configuration for it. Thus, you need to set the config per topic if you want to change it.

Comment: I described in my post that the topic was created with delete.retention.ms=100 which means that tombstone marker key would have been cleaned up after 100 ms after being sent. One question: can it be related to compact.policy setting? I read somewhere that we need to set it to compact, delete to enable deletes as well.

Comment: If you enable "compact,delete" you get basically a TTL on top and records that are older then retention time will be deleted (even if there is no tombstone). Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist

Can you double check the topic config, that it is really configured with delete.retention.ms=100 ?

Comment: I ran --describe on the topic and the output is Configs:min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01,delete.retention.ms=100,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.ms=100

Comment: Making delete.retention.ms=0 should delete tombstone in your case. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Moreover, produce 1111:null message using Kafka Java client. Null in 1111:null will be treated as string if you produce aforementioned message using bin/kafka-console-producer.sh.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Could you elaborate a little bit on "If the consumer implements a cache, it could happen that the record gets never deleted."? Why this may happen?

Comment: If the cache delete only if it reads a tombstone, and the consumer if offline for whatever reason for a long time, and a tombstone is written and delete the record, and the tombstone is deleted immediately, too, the consumer will have a "dangling" entry in the cache as it will never see the tombstone.

Answer (score 16):

Compacted topic has two portions:

1) Cleaned portion: Portion of kafka log cleaned by kafka cleaner at least once.

2) Dirty portion: Portion of kafka log not cleaned by kafka cleaner even once until now. Kafka maintains dirty offset. All messages with offset >= dirty offset belong to dirty portion.

Note: Kafka cleaner cleans all segments (irrespective of whether segment is in cleaned/dirty portion) and re-copies them every time dirty ratio reaches min.cleanable.dirty.ratio.

Tombstones are deleted segment wise. Tombstones in a segment are deleted if segment satisfies below conditions:

1. Segment should be in cleaned portion of log.
2. Last modified time of segment should be <= (Last modified time of segment containing a message with offset=(dirty offset - 1)) - delete.retention.ms.

It is difficult to elaborate second point but in simple terms, Second point implies => Segment size should be equal to log.segment.bytes/segment.bytes (1GB by default). For segment size (in cleaner portion) to be equal to 1GB, you need to produce large number of messages with distinctive keys. But you produced only 4 messages with 3 messages having same key. That is why tombstones are not deleted in segment containing 1111:null message (Segment doesn't satisfy second point I mentioned above).

You have two options to delete tombstones with 4 messages:

1. make delete.retention.ms=0 or
2. make log.segment.bytes/segment.bytes=50.

**Source Code (Extra Reading):**
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/LogCleaner.scala

```
try {
      // clean segments into the new destination segment
      for (old <- segments) {
        val retainDeletes = old.lastModified > deleteHorizonMs
        info("Cleaning segment %s in log %s (largest timestamp %s) into %s, %s deletes."
            .format(old.baseOffset, log.name, new Date(old.largestTimestamp), cleaned.baseOffset, if(retainDeletes) "retaining" else "discarding"))
        cleanInto(log.topicPartition, old, cleaned, map, retainDeletes, log.config.maxMessageSize, stats)
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm for removing the tombstone in a compacted is supposed to be the following.

1. Tombstone is never removed when it's still in the dirty portion of the log.
2. After the tombstone is in the cleaned portion of the log, we further delay the removal of the tombstone by delete.retention.ms since the time the tombstone is in the cleaned portion.

It's possible that the tombstones are still in the dirty portion of the log and hence not cleared. Triggering a few more messages of different keys should push the tombstones into the cleaned portion of the log and delete them.

Comment: I have verified @yatishby 's solution, it works. first, download the [kcat](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat), then use this command `echo "i:1" | kcat -b localhost:9092 -t test -Z -K:`  to produce multiple messages to the Kafka broker. It will push the tombstone to the tail of the log and trigger the removal of the tombstone.

Answer (score 2):

From the compaction perspective, the kafka log contains three parts:

1. active segment, to which the new record will be appended.
2. log head, which has not yet been compacted.
3. log tail, which has been compacted or being compacted.

[image]

> Kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_compactionconfig):
>
> Note that this compaction deadline is `not a hard guarantee` since it is still subjected to the availability of log cleaner threads and the actual compaction time. You will want to monitor the uncleanable-partitions-count, max-clean-time-secs and max-compaction-delay-secs metrics.

As @yatishby pointed out, if your tombstone is in the active segment or the log head, the compaction won't be triggered.

Therefore, I tried to flush dozens of messages to the topic and move the tombstone from the log head to the log tail.

Then, it works, the tombstones have been successfully removed.

Here are the steps to reproduce it.

### Step1: send tombstone to Kafka

I have created a test topic with the same configuration as you. then send tombstones to Kafka. Even though `delete.retention.ms=100` has been specified, as you can see, the tombstones stay there. it seems not working.

[image]

### Step2: flush identical messages to Kafka.

```
# do it 20 times.
echo "g:1" | kcat -b localhost:9092 -t test -Z -K:
echo "j:1" | kcat -b localhost:9092 -t test -Z -K:
```

> [Kcat](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat) is a very convenient tool to produce messages to kafka.

### Step3: The tombstones have disappeared.

[image]

### Cheatsheet

1. How to produce a tombstone to Kafka using the [kcat](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat)?

   ```
   echo "yourkey:" | kcat -b localhost:9092 -t test -Z -K:
   ```
2. how to consume messages from a topic?

   ```
   kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test  \
   --from-beginning \                             
   --formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter \
   --property print.timestamp=true \
   --property print.key=true \
   --property print.value=true
   ```