# Delete single records from a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to delete a single record from a kafka topic? I know there is the script kafka-delete-records.sh that deletes the records that are before the specified offset on a specified topic and partition, but I want to be able to delete a record on an offset I specify. Is there a way to do that?

This is not on Java but on the bare kafka instance.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: just in case the data published is corrupted and to remove it so it wont interfere with other microservices consuming from the kafka instance

Comment: How do you define "corrupt"? Maybe you should implement record validation and filtering on the produers to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a compacted Topic you can mark a record as a 'tombstone' by publishing a message for the key you want to indicate is deleted with a null value. See answers here: [Kafka not deleting key with tombstone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632713/kafka-not-deleting-key-with-tombstone)

If the topic is not compacted, the record must be removed through retention policies. You cannot target individual offsets to remove.